# SocketIo - Setting socket variables does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I setup a simple Socket server `gameIo` with nodejs

```
gameIo.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on("sign up", () => {
    socket.john = "john"
    console.log(socket.john) //returns "john"
  })

  socket.on("sign out", () => {
    console.log(socket.john) //returns undefined
  })
})
```

On the frontend, I emit a `sign up` first, and then an `sign out`. However, `socket.john` does not seem to register the new value.

Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Try doing a `console.log(socket.id)` in both of those events and see if you get the same `socket.id` for both events.  Adding a custom property should work if it's truly the same `socket` object.

Comment: Ohh interesting, thanks! Yes, the `socket.id` was different. I seem to be connecting to the backend multiple times. (Must be because of React render cycles. I should probably send a single request instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `console.log(socket.id)` to each event handler to see if you see the same `socket.id` each time.  Adding a custom property on the socket object should work just fine if it is indeed the same socket object so it seems likely that what you're seeing is two different socket objects.